# Loop through huge CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv

I have to loop through a file with ~50.000 rows each day to generate reports and import those data records into our database

Since I have to execute some `-replace` -statements and stuff I currently loop through each row via `foreach`. This approach finishes after ~16 Minutes:

```
$csv_file = ".\testfile.csv"
$csv_import = Import-Csv $csv_file -Delimiter ";" -Encoding "default"

function Import-CsvVersion1 {
    $results = @()

    foreach ($data in $csv_import) {
        $properties = [ordered]@{
            id          = $data."id"
            name        = $data."name"
            description = $data."description"
            netcost     = $data."netcost"
            rrp         = $data."rrp"
        }
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
    }

    # Export $results into final csv
}
```

I found another approach where the result of the `foreach` will be assigned directly to the `$results` variable. This approach finished after ~8 Minutes (so it needs only half of the time):

```
$csv_file = ".\testfile.csv"
$csv_import = Import-Csv $csv_file -Delimiter ";" -Encoding "default"

function Import-CsvVersion2 {
    $results = foreach ($data in $csv_import) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            id          = $data."id"
            name        = $data."name"
            description = $data."description"
            netcost     = $data."netcost"
            rrp         = $data."rrp"
        }
    }

    # Export $results into final csv
}
```

I've read somewhere that a loop via `ForEach-Object` may be even faster - unfortunately I don't know how to start with this.

Comment: try `$csv_import | Foreach-Object {$_."id"}` the `$_` is the equivalent to `$data`. hope that helps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6)

Comment: you could also measure your commands (maybe the import is what takes so long) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Measure-Object?view=powershell-6

Comment: Thanks @GuentherSchmitz - I'll try your `Foreach-Object` approach. I already used `Measure-Command` to get the above mentioned Minutes for both functions :)

Comment: Your first function is slower because the `+=` in `$results += New-Object psobject -Property $properties` rebuilds the object everytime. And the bigger it gets, the longer it will take. Instead use an ArrayList. That is able to use the `.add()` method. `$results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`

Comment: Thanks @T-Me - I didn't know that `+=` rebuilds the array. That obviously explains the big time-difference

Comment: To address your last paragraph: `ForEach-Object` is actually *slower* than `foreach`, but it's less memory-consuming, because it avoids reading the entire data into memory first (when used correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GuentherSchmitz I was able to create the third test-function. In the next test I used a CSV-file with ~2.000 rows the results where:

- `Import-CsvVersion1` -> 4 Minute(s) 24 Seconds
- `Import-CsvVersion2` -> 0 Minute(s) 18 Seconds
- `Import-CsvVersion3` -> 1 Minute(s) 20 Seconds

Thanks again for the help :-)

P.S: I also got rid of a former `Write-Progress` which apparently slowed the script down by about 80%

Comment: Maybe the solution is even simpler, depending on what you need to do: ``import-csv "filename.csv" | Select Id, Name, Description, NetCost, RRP | Export-csv $newfile``

Comment: Hi @Joost - "unfortunately" I need to manipulate the data in a huge scale (for instance I need to do about 12 replacements for the "description")

Comment: Even in that case, using hash tables in the ``Select-Object``, you could accomplish the same thing:
``Import-Csv "filename.csv" | Select Id, Name, @{l="Description";e={$_.Description.Replace('1','one').Replace(' - ',' / ')}}, NetCost, RRP | Export-csv $newfile``
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6

Comment: PS: if that becomes unreadable, you can wrap the replacements in a custom function and then use ``Select ..., @{l="Description";e={ReplaceText $_.Description}}, ...``